# Reinstalling Windows Phone to Android

Tags: installation, windows, operating-system

Is it possible to change phone OS from Windows Phone to Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All my research tells me mainly **No**. There are ways of doing this on older Windows Mobile Phones, and on full-fat x86 Windows tablets (not 'RT'), but there seem to be no ways of doing so on Windows 7/8 phones for levels early-adopter or higher. The reason for the unusual wording of the previous sentence is that I am almost positive that this is doable, but would require some serious, pioneer-level hardware/software chops, as very few people have a motivation to make this work.

For Google and Microsoft, the conflict is obvious. Each would rather you buy a phone from their partners, and then use their services. Android phone geeks would likely consider it not worth the effort, as they would have to illegally hack the Windows phone to figure it out (their internal bits are proprietary), and Android devices of almost any category can now be had for less than $200. Windows phone geeks face the proprietary thing, plus they would rather you use Windows Phone OS.

The last time I saw a real effort to port Android to a device less popular than IOS and Windows Desktop was the HP Touchpad running WebOS. This was a 10' tablet selling for $99 in a fire sale, when most/all other tablets cost $400+. So there was a real value motive involved.

If your phone is "Windows Mobile", (read: several years old), there likely are ways of installing older versions of Android on it. But most of them are device-specific, so I would need to know more to help you out.

Bottom line: probably not worth the effort, even on the outside chance that I could send you a list of instructions that a non-professional could understand and carry out.

Comment: I asked for this not because I consider the OS change, it was just the curiosity. Thank you for your answer, it leaves no other questions to answer in this topic for me.